# Upsert account and filled in related lists

Tags: upsert

I'm using DataLoader for the first time and I have successfully used "upsert" to create new accounts. But I can't really get my head around the following:

In my salesforce sandbox (which simulates a gas service company) each account has the following objects attached: Premise, Gas Service Point, Gas Meter and an Invoice. How do I make it so that all these objects are filled and linked using just one upsert. Is that possible?

I've tried adding all the information in a .csv file but in the dataloader I don't see the mappings that I need. So there's no link other than to the fields from the "Account" object.

I wish I could have tried more before coming here for help. But the truth is that I find the above process a little vague. So I am actually not sure where to even look for a possible solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use one single upsert operation to load all this data, you'll need one operation per object.

As for the relationship mapping, you need to set the external ID field on the Account as the relationship identifier when setting up the data load operation.

This is covered in some detail [here](http://blog.ryansieve.com/2013/03/14/using-salesforce-com-data-loader-upsert-with-an-external-id/)

Answer (score 0):

If its an upsert : technically it should be able to take care of update and insert operation in a single go.  I would recommend check the relationships each objects share. In the file, ensure to maintain a proper sequence of records. I.e. sequence order : keep the Parent Objects first and then put the child objects to load.THis way by the time child would be ready to load,your database would already have parent record.